# Mouse DPI options in Microsoft's Mouse and Keyboard Center [Wireless Mouse 1000]

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, wireless-mouse

I've downloaded Microsoft's Mouse and Keyboard Center for my Wireless Mouse 1000 and it seems like there are no sensitivity settings where i could change my DPI. Is it because my mouse supports only deafult DPI settings or is it matter of installing different software?

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse simply does not have the ability to modify its DPI settings.  If you need that functionality, you need to find a mouse that supports that feature.